# How to read data from a specific column in a text file

Tags: c++

I'm having a text file with some columns

```
 name,age,address,gender
```

I know I can access a line with `getline();`, but when I get the string with the data that `getline();` returned I want to read some specific column. How do I do that ?

I saw a solution to this problem but it was in java which I don't know yet, so I decided to post this for a c++ answer

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Text files don't have columns. Text files have lines. You will have to "decode" the "columns" yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be it you are asking in Java or C++, the approach will be similar.

After you have read the entire line. Split the line by its delimiter.

In Java, it is just

```
line.split(",");
```

In C++, you could use `str.find(",")` to get the position of the comma. Then substring the delimited tokens out.

Set a `count` variable to count number of tokens you have delimited so far to get to your desired column.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is the same: read the file line by line and tokenize, while taking the second elem of the array if I want to see the second column.
It can be improved because it does lots of copies but the idea is here.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>   

std::string line;
vector<string> strs;
std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    strs.clear();
    boost::split(strs,line,boost::is_any_of("\t"));
    cout<<"age ="<<strs[1]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: This is very inefficient.

Comment: yes, it could be improved, but that shows how things work as a first cut.

Comment: You should at least warn about the excessive allocations and copies.

Answer (score 0):

You may also parse the C string (if you use STL strings do copy the C string to a char array!) using strtok. It will work pretty well, although the need for a separate copy is due to the fact that strtok does modify the string as well as some static memory (or, perhaps, thread-local storage; I wouldn't rely on it)